# unique_ptr has no member function

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I am updating my gcc 4.4 to gCC 4.7, I will do this to use 4.7.

My problem is when I use `unique_ptr`. I wrote this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <CL/cl.h>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  std::unique_ptr<cl_platform_id[]>yt;
  yt = std::unique_ptr<icl_platform_id[]> (new cl_platform_id [3]);


  /* yt.get()[0] = ...... */ this is error no member found

    return 0;
}
```

but I want to use `yt` member such as `uique_ptr::get()` and the only function that I get is `operator*`, so what is the problem?

Edited:

here is my problem:
http://image-load.biz/?di=6FBY

Comment: I use gcc 4.7 and have no problem with get. Could you provide a small sample that reproduces the problem, without the CL stuff?

Comment: i have no error message , but i can't found get member on any other member except operator* member .

Comment: Is it legal to have a `unique_ptr` to an unsized array?

Comment: If you actually want to use that unique_ptr, you'll need to initialize it with a new cl_platform_id[].  Then you'll be able to use (*yt)[1] etc...

Comment: i try to initialized but , i still cant access to this element ( no get function found)

Comment: @MarkB seems like potential memory leak, because unique_ptr use delete operator (instead of delete[]) to free resource under control

Comment: @vnm That wouldn't be a memory leak unless cl_platform_id had a destructor which needed calling which also dellocated memory.

Comment: @Benj - It is undefined behavior to `delete` (as opposed to `delete[]`) something allocated with `new[]`. It may leak memory or worse.

Comment: (Which it doesn't because it's a C-Style POD struct)

Comment: @FredLarson - It isn't undefined behavior but it does assume that the default global delete operator hasn't been overridden and that you are using a POD.  It's bad practice but it will never leak assuming those assumptions are true.

Comment: her is image that explain the problem http://image-load.biz/?di=6FBY

Comment: @Benj It doesn't matter whether it's POD or not, the behavior is undefined and anything can happen, including a memory leak.

Comment: @Benj - Read this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.13

Comment: @FredLarson - Yes I've read that before, like I say, it's not "undefined" because the default delete operator defines it.  It is bad (as I said).  However, I do wonder who in their right mind would override the global delete operator.

Comment: Anyway, this is all fairly irrelavent since unqiue_ptr has a partial specialization which handles arrays and does call delete[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a problem with your IDE's member suggestions. `std::unique_ptr` certainly does have a member `pointer get() const noexcept;`, in both the default template and the partial specialisation for arrays.

If you type `get()` yourself, then the compiler should be happy. Unfortunately, I've never used that IDE, so I can't help you fix its autocompleter.

Whether you should be calling `get()` is another question; you can access the array elements as `yt[0]` etc. `get()` is only for those rare occasions when you actually need a raw pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<cl_platform_id[]> yt ( new cl_platform_id[3] );
yt[0].some_member();
```

Comment: my problem is not in init the member but my problem is , i have no member except operator*

Comment: Just spotted the screenshot, are you sure that it's just that your IDE doesn't know how to parse it properly?  What happens if you compile assuming that the member is there.

Comment: yes it compile it ! i think that mine problem is with ide thank you

Comment: Yes, remember C++ is not like Java (which has reflection and can thus tell an IDE how to parse itself), it's tricky to parse templates properly and not all IDEs do a great job of it.